# Deployment Tests on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I would like to have Heroku automatically run tests prior to deployment, such that if the tests pass the deploy will be reversed/ not happen. We are using Django's standard test library and considering APIRequestFactory for our Rest Framework endpoints.

In general this is how the process should work:

[start deploy to Heroku] -> [code is copied and packages/ migrations ran] -> [tests are ran] -> [if test passes, deploy, otherwise do not deploy and throw error]

How can I set this up? I know I can run something along the lines of `heroku run python manage.py test` but this is not automatic and requires the code to be deployed first.

Comment: I'm going to simultaneously VTC this as off-topic since I think you're asking for a tool/library recommendation, and then recommend a tool/library that does this: [Travis CI has Heroku integration](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/heroku).

Comment: I was originally thinking that Heroku could do this in itself, wasn't expecting to have to use a CI tool like Travis CI. That being said, can Travis CI specifically run tests on the Heroku servers or is it done locally?

Comment: My guess is you could set it to do either. I haven't set it up myself. I think the default is that it runs your test on Heroku and if they fail it simply does not complete the push.

Comment: @Rob, Heroku recently released Heroku CI, which might be of help. It is actually a simple one-off dyno which acts like a CI server, so it will perfectly emulate the actual environment of your project. It can be used with Heroku Pipelines only, as per my knowledge.